# Can't access req from context

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, koa2

I'm using Koa.js with Apollo Server's `apollo-server-koa`.

I've debug the `{ req }` and the value is undefined.
I've followed the documentation, but still got no clue.
Even if I access the `req.headers.authorization` and put this on HTTP Header of graphql gui:

```
{
  "authorization": "bla"
}
```

the value is still `undefined`.

app.ts:

```
import cors from "@koa/cors";
import Koa from "koa";

import config from "./config/environtment";
import server from "./server";

const PORT: number = config.port;

async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const app: Koa = new Koa();

    server.applyMiddleware({ app });

    app
      .use(cors())
      .listen(PORT, () =>
        console.log(
          `Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`,
        ),
      );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

bootstrap();
```

server.ts:

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-koa";

import typeDefs from "./graphql/schema";
import resolvers from "./graphql/resolvers";
import context from "./graphql/context";

export default new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context,
});
```

context.ts

```
export default ({ req }) => {
  console.log(req) // return undefined.
  return {
    test: "test",
  };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are specific to `apollo-server`, which uses `apollo-server-express` under the hood. I believe for `apollo-server-koa`, the options are passed in an object with a `ctx` field that holds the Koa [Context](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/context.md). So the following should work:

```
export default ({ ctx }) => {
  console.log(ctx.request)
  console.log(ctx.response)
  return {};
};
```